# Hive [Error 10025] Expression not in GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, hive

The first query works well. But the second query is giving error "[Error 10025] Expression not in GROUP BY key ''-3''  ".  I read related posting and so far I am not sure how to fix the error.

Thank you very much for your help on this.

Query #1

```
SELECT case when user_id = '-3' then cast(order_id as varchar(255)) else user_id end as user_id2
from orders
where user_id = '-3'
```

Query #2

```
SELECT case when user_id = '-3' then cast(order_id as varchar(255)) else user_id end as user_id2
       ,sum(order_value) as sales
from orders
group by 1


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/net1/liulu001/conversant/troubleshooting_userid.py", line 28, in <module>
cursor.execute(q)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 302, in execute
configuration=configuration)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 343, in execute_async
self._execute_async(op)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 362, in _execute_async
operation_fn()
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 340, in op
async=True)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 1027, in execute
return self._operation('ExecuteStatement', req)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 957, in _operation
resp = self._rpc(kind, request)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 925, in _rpc
err_if_rpc_not_ok(response)
File "/home/net1/liulu001/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 704, in err_if_rpc_not_ok
raise HiveServer2Error(resp.status.errorMessage)
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED:       SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 3:13 Expression not in GROUP BY key ''-3''
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not aggregating in the first query so the `group by` is not required.
In the second query `group by 1` is treated as constant. Use `group by case when user_id = '-3' then cast(order_id as varchar(255)) else user_id end` instead.

Or  if you want to be able to reference your column names by position instead of by name, then try this before your query:

```
set hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I have tried using the group by syntax you suggested and got similar error.  But I just tried it again and it worked fine.  So problem solved.  Thanks again!

Comment: So, do you satisfied with my answer? Then please vote or accept or suggest how can I improve the answer please.

Comment: Yes, satisfied with the answer.  Just voted useful.  I guess the 0 didn't change until the votes reach certain threshold?  Thanks again!